# How to open a second ptinker Window separately rather than as a tab

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to open a second window in tkinter but it always appears as a tab rather than separately. Code showing the problem is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        button = tk.Button(frame, text = 'New Window', width = 25, command = self.new_window)
        button.pack()
        frame.pack()

    def new_window(self):
        newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        SecondWindow(newWindow)

class SecondWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        quitButton = tk.Label(frame, text = 'Second Window')
        quitButton.pack()
        frame.pack()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run this I get the following output:

[image]

Clicking the button gives:

[image]

(Ignoring the secondary issue of the size) if we expand it we get the following:
[image]

I can get a separate window by dragging the tab.  How to I code this so that I get the window displaying as a separate window when I click the button ?

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem on Ubuntu

Comment: I am running this on Mac OS X 10.14

Comment: This is interesting, I wasn't aware that Tkinter had any built-in ability to do tabbed windows like that.  Try omitting the parameter to `Toplevel()`.

Comment: I don't get this behavior on my mac with 10.14. I'm guessing there's a user preference somewhere that turns on tabbed windows.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on windows either. Thought I would be interested to know this feature if it is one.

Comment: Would you happen to be using a GUI Builder or Anaconda? And to answer your question your code should work as you want it to. The odd behavior you are seeing is not normal for the code you have shown.

Comment: @BryanOakley - you got it. There's a preference in Mac under "Dock" which was set to always open new windows as tabs. Just didn't consider it was a mac thing. Thanks ! Can I mark this as answered ? Should I post this as the answer ?